# How to get upgrade history for a package in a production environment?

Tags: package, production

I need to know the previous versions of a package installed in a org.Is there a way to get that information?

Answer (score 1):

Setup -> App Setup -> Installed Packages which will give you an overview of the packages installed, publisher, version number, installed date.

You can also click on one of the packages and go View Components to look at what that package has installed.

Comment: but how to see upgrade history for a particular package,this will not show components added at what versions,or changes made to existing components

Comment: I`m not sure you can, if the upgrade has been successful than it will list the current version. Unless you have a version control system set up. There is an idea listed here about your requirement : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq78AAC

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm not too sure about this, is there a way at least check which last version was upgraded?